How to use xml text style in Jetpack Compose Text composable?
I'm working on legacy project for which I can't migrate xml text styles due to time & other organisation constraints so is there any way to use the existing xml text styles in Text composable as I'm doing new implementation in jetpack-compose.
P.S. - How to refer xml style from Jetpack Compose Modifier? answer  is creating fresh compose TextStyle. I don't want to do that, I'm looking for a way to use xml text appearance styles in compose.

Does this answer your question? How to refer xml style from Jetpack Compose Modifier?

@Leviathan Nope that is creating Compose Text Styles. I don't want to do that I want to use existing xml styles only in compose.

You might not like the answer ("You can't do that [...] create compose TextStyle"), but it seems to be the same question after all and hence the same answer would apply.

You can try using xml-TextView component inside AndroidView and add text style to it instead of using compose TextView

There is official AppCompat Theme Adapter but it's limited and now deprecated.
